# How to prevent ArcGIS Pro Arcade expression adding one month on to my desired date?

Tags: arcgis-pro, date, arcade

I am trying to add dates to two date fields in ArcGIS Pro using expressions in Arcade.

When I use the expression `Date(2020,10,29)` the result in the field is 29/11/2020, which is one month later than my desired date. The same thing has happened in the next field for a different date which should be 01/01/1983 but is resulting in 01/02/1983:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known limitation and considered as a BUG found in ArcGIS Pro 2.5 and will be fixed in upcoming versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a BUG or will be fixed.

In Arcade the calculation of the month is a little bit confusing, because it uses the numbers from from 0-11, where 0 is January and 11 is December.

https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/date_functions/